# R formatC gives not same output with the same parameter

Tags: r, format, significant-digits

Ich have a numeric value (`x1=0.01`) which I want to format with two significant digits:

```
> p_digits <- 2
> x1 <- 0.01
> str(x1)
  num 0.01
> formatC(x1, format = "fg", digits = p_digits, flag = "#", big.mark = "'")
```

which gives:

```
[1] "0.010"
```

Now, I retrieve the same value from a dataframe with structure

```
> str(df0)
'data.frame':   328 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ analyse   : chr  "ALAT/GPT" "ALAT/GPT" "Albumin" "Albumin" ...
 $ min       : num  NA 1 35 1 0 0 0 0 36 1 ...
 $ max       : num  35 5000 55 200 20 NA 30 7000 92 3000 ...

> x2 <- subset(df0, analyse == "somewhat")$min
> x2
[1] 0.01
> str(x2)
  num 0.01
```

Now, if I format `x2` I get:

```
> formatC(x2, format = "fg", digits = p_digits, flag = "#", big.mark = "'")
[1] "0.0100"
```

In summary, I have two numeric parameters `x1` and `x2` with both the same value 0.01 which gives me different outputs using formatC.

Update 1: The dataframe was built by importing a MySQL table with ODBC.

Update 2: Different results depending from figure with small deviation

```
> x3 <- 0.0101111
> formatC(x3, format = "fg", digits = 2, flag = "#", big.mark = "'")
[1] "0.010"

> x4 <- 0.0099999
> formatC(x4, format = "fg", digits = 2, flag = "#", big.mark = "'")
[1] "0.0100"
```

For me it is not clear why `x4` gives 3 significant digits.

Comment: is `all.equal(x1, x2)` `TRUE` ?

Comment: Good point. It gives me: `"Mean relative difference: 2.235174e-08"`.

Comment: If I round with `round(x2,2)` I got the result I want: `formatC(round(x2,2), format = "fg", digits = 2, flag = "#", big.mark = "'")` gives `0.010`. Nevertheless, for me it is not clear why this happend, see update 2.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed `p_digits` in the meanwhile? At least I can not reproduce your observations.

```
p_digits  <- 2

x1 <- 0.01
str(x1)
formatC(x1, format = "fg", digits = p_digits, flag = "#", big.mark = "'")
#[1] "0.010"

df0  <- data.frame(analyse=c("somewhat","a","b"), min=c(.01, 9000, .01234))
x2 <- subset(df0, analyse == "somewhat")$min
formatC(x2, format = "fg", digits = p_digits, flag = "#", big.mark = "'")
#[1] "0.010"

x3 <- 0.0101111
formatC(x3, format = "fg", digits = 2, flag = "#", big.mark = "'")
#[1] "0.010"

x4 <- 0.0099999
formatC(x4, format = "fg", digits = 2, flag = "#", big.mark = "'")
#[1] "0.010"
```

CHANGES IN R 3.6.0: Calls like formatC(*, zero.print = "< 0.001") no longer give an error and are further improved via new optional argument replace.zero. Reported by David Hugh-Jones.

Comment: Sorry, I missed p_digits. The problem may be that x1 and x2 are not identical. See comment of Ronak Shah and my update 1.

Comment: @giordano I still can not reproduce your output. Different R-Versions? (3.6.1)

Comment: I have version R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26). Thanks! I will try the new vesion as soon as possible.

Comment: I installed version `R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)` but still I get `"0.0100"` with `x4=0.009999`.

Comment: I at least get "0.010". Maybe then this comes from the C-library? I compile R under `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` Debian 10.

Comment: @giordano If I run `x4 <- 0.0099999; formatC(x4, format = "fg", digits = 2, flag = "#", big.mark = "'")` on the console at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/formatC it also returns `"0.010"`.